# Some real interview questions C++

Tags: c++

So I compiled some interview questions I was asked. I answered some and noted down the answers to the ones I could not. Some questions are not C specific and are general. Everyone can add their input to the questions. No obligation to follow the answers I wrote!

Q1: What would be the size of a pointer on a 2 bit system and a 16 bit system?
A: 2 bits and 2 bytes

Q2: Why did we need OOPs/classes when in C we had structs and could achieve the same?
A: Leave this to SO users to answer!

Q3: If you were told to divide a program into distinct parts for an embedded system, what would they be?
A: IO part and CPU part

Q4: What are some hardware level benefits of using threads? Any give a single example for a single CPU (single core)          A: One thread would be doing some number crunching, the other just living for a millisec could
signal an event to read the hard drive.

Q5: If we had a pointer `char* p = NULL`, what would `cout<<sizeof(*p)` print?                      A: the size of `char`, not `char*`. Which means the amount of memory it can point to, not the size of the pointer itself

Q6: Which functions do function pointers point to in a virtual table?                           A: Virtual functions

Q7: How would you calculate how many threads a program needs to generate for an optimal performance for a single CPU (single core)? Will you do a physical test or can you automate your program? Give an example. Or both, again an example.
A: SO users your answer here!

Q8: If a virtual function (not pure), is inheritance, is not implemented in the derived class. Now, If I have a base class pointer to a derived class object, and then make a call 
`baseObject->function()`, what will happen? Will there be any problem at any point in compile time/run time?                                                                                   A: None. :)

Comment: Can you ask these as separate questions? And please search for duplicates before posting, I'm sure some of these questions have already been answered on SO.

Comment: Well, i thought so but I'd put Q# so that anyone answering would write and answer as A# or something to make it easier to read.

Comment: What position do those questions cover ? Junior Level ? Mid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A1** 2 bits and 16 bits is the obvious answer. I 'd ask for clarification like "in technical terms, what exactly do you mean 2-bit system" just to make sure.

**A2** This is OOP 101 material... a short answer might be "Because classes enable inheritance, and inheritance enables many useful paradigms (most importantly polymorphism) that decrease code complexity".

**A3** I 'm afraid I would not consider your answer correct. You should definitely have asked "what kind of program" to get a general idea: is it a service? a script? a desktop application? With no additional input, I would answer "divide into UI and business logic".

**A4** On a hardware level, threads enable your application to have better utilization of your hardware resources (e.g. multiple CPU cores). An example would be any divide-and-conquer algorithm, where the divided work can run on multiple threads in parallel (e.g. many sorting algorithms). I would again consider your answer to be wrong.

**A5** Correct.

**A6** Correct.

**A7** First of all: see if the program is CPU-bound (some quick and dirty measuring would tell you this). If it not CPU-bound, then most possibly one thread would be enough. If it is, then you want to use as many threads as possible (which means as many as the pieces you can partition your work into), up to the number of threads your hardware can execute at the same time.

**A8** Correct: No problem, the base class implementation would be called.

Comment: @Jon, Thanks for the answers. I edited Q3, it was a question for embedded system.

Comment: A1: 2-bit is much more commonly used to refer to "cheap". So yes, clarification may be necessary, this may not be a computing question after all.

Comment: @Jon, edited the questions to be precise. Thanks anyway.

Comment: A7: not quite right. You're assuming that threads are never blocked from execution. This is rarely the case. Usually people end up needing more threads than available execution cores. The answer is something like (available execution cores)*(average thread run time) / (average thread cpu time).

Comment: @martona: Indeed I am. That's why I said "possibly". Also, keep in mind that there is no reason to assume threads would block: there are async programming techniques that do not require blocking threads.

Comment: Inheritance does not enable polymorphism. These are two distinct concepts. In fact, C supports polymorphism.

Comment: WTF A5 correct? talking about 101. if you fail a null-dereference question in an interview then that's one red flag.

Comment: A6 I wouldn't take as correct. The question checks if you understand what virtual functions mean in the implementation detail, and the answer doesn't show he knows.

Comment: A8 is not complete. It depends on how the function is implemented. If it calls the base class' function then there will be a linker error, because the function isn't defined. If somewhere in the code you call the base function then again that's a linker error. To solve this you want to either provide a definition (even if empty) or make the base function a pure virtual.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: **[a2]** Technically the answer is not "correct". Please keep in mind I was trying to answer in 2 lines, not write an essay. **[a5]** You are mistaken, there's no null dereference going on there. `sizeof` does not evaluate its argument. **[a6]** Difference of opinion there. **[a8]** The OP says the function is not pure virtual, so it *has to be* implemented in the base class. I don't know what you are talking about it not being defined.

Comment: @Jon a function never _has_ to be implemented. Just don't call the function that's not defined and everything is fine. If you do call it then it has to either be defined or be a pure virtual so the compiler stops you from being silly.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Well, you are right in that you can leave it unimplemented *deliberately*. I still don't think that this is what the question says.

Answer (score -1):

Uhm.. not C++ exactly, but this:

Imagine you have two hosts, a provider, their router, admins, and a lot of beer. You want to Telnet one host from the other one using 192.168.0.5 (the other host private address). Is that possible?

A:Yep, sure it's possible. Everything is possible with admins when you have a lot of beer.

(It's a real question I got on an interview once in my life. Well, some good humor during in an interview can help the man relax and, well, kinda make the atmosphere in the interview lighter, you know what I mean.)

This should be Community Wiki, shouldn't it? And there is a duplicate of this somewhere, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Not even C++ *sort of*. The question is already pushing the limits of being on topic; answers like this don't exactly help.

Comment: I consider this question to be humorous or at least trying to look so. Don't know what the author meant, but for me, any "interview question example" questions are a good laugh, for an obvious reason. They're absolutely useless, and people asking then obviously don't understand that only real deep knowledge of the subject is what helps, not learning some well-known or previously asked questions by heart.

Comment: True, however interview questions tests our deep knowledge :)
I strongly oppose who start with interview questions rather good books.